# Phonegap - unable to play local sound file

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to play a local sound file with Phonegap. This works fine over http, but doesn't for local files. I can see the files on the device and play them manually but cannot do so with Phonegap's API. I've tried:

1. .mp3 and .wav file formats.
2. Putting the files in www/ (with path
   `/android_asset/www/sound.mp3`) and /sdcard/ (with path `sound.mp3`).
3. Varying the protocol (with or without file://).

But nothing seems to work, neither the success nor the error callback gets called. I'm also making sure the file actually exists before trying to play it. Here's my code:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {

                        var directoryReader = fs.root.createReader();
                        directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                            for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                                if (entries[i].isFile && entries[i].name.match(/.*\.wav$/)){

                                    var audio = new Media(entries[i].toURL().substr(19), function(){console.log('success');}, function(){console.log('error');});
                                    console.log("!!!!! " + audio.getDuration());
                                    audio.play();
                                    audio.release();    
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }, function (error) {
                            alert(error.code);
                        })
                   }, function (error) {
                           alert(error.code);
                   });
```

`audio.getDuration` always returns -1. I'm using Phonegap 1.9 on an Android Nexus S running Android 2.3.3 and the app is targeted at API level 2.1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getDuration` returns -1 when you call it synchronously. You need to call it in a setInterval loop like shown here http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.getDuration to get the correct duration.

I don't think you can play files from assets/www, but files on the sdcard work perfectly fine. You need to make sure that you don't pass the full path from the FileEntry object. You need to trim off the starting path (file:///mnt/sdcard/) since the media player plugin adds that by itself. I found that out after an hour or so of head scratching!