# phonegap media mp3 location

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [access files from assets/www directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326272/access-files-from-assets-www-directory)

I'm writing android app using phonegap and want to play mp3 on click in the button, my mp3 is located in the www folder. Unfortunately I tried to use "android_asset/ww/sample.mp3" as a src for new Media(src, Succ, Err); and file is not played. Is that path correct ? I'm using Cordova 2.0.0 and Eclipse.

Comment: See the answer posted here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559763/phonegap-unable-to-play-local-sound-file/11563390#11563390

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted this out, looks like from cordova version 2.0.0 there is some bug that doesn't allow to play local files (remote works fine). I took a step back and used cordova-1.9.0 and it works fine with path "/android_asset/www/sample.mp3"

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///android_asset/www/foo.html", onResolveSuccess, onFail);
```

Comment: I've no idea how to use it, trying to run example from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#LocalFileSystem  , but only thing I get is the fileSystem.name is persistent.  I use "file:///android_asset/www/sample.mp3" , any idea ?